# Easy way to rename multiple columns using either a text function or find & replace

Tags: powerquery, m

Is there an easy way to rename multiple columns in a table using either a text function (like [`Text.Upper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-upper) or [`Text.Proper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-proper), etc), or a find & replace (like [`Text.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-replace))?

I have tried the [`Table.RenameColumns()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-renamecolumns) function, but that requires knowing the new name of the column beforehand.

---

I've checked these questions, but they're not quite specific enough for my use-case:

- [How to rename headers using a loop in Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874142/how-to-rename-headers-using-a-loop-in-power-bi)
- [How to find & replace in all columns with Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758550/how-to-find-replace-in-all-columns-with-power-bi)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new step in your table's **Advance Query Editor** as below-

```
Table.TransformColumnNames(#"your_previous_step_name",Text.Upper)
```

You can check [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=power%20bi%20change%20all%20column%20name%20to%20uppercase&rlz=1C1ONGR_enBD1018BD1018&oq=power%20bi%20change%20all%20column%20name%20to%20u&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i160l3j33i22i29i30l6.11958j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_rNerY6XSO5GKseMP6N6ZeA_33) simple tutorial for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Here you go:

```fs
let
  fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextFunction = 
    ( tbl_Table as table
    , optional lst_Columns as nullable list
    , optional fun_TextFunction as nullable function
    ) as table =>
      let
        fun_Function = if fun_TextFunction is null then Text.Upper else fun_TextFunction,
        lst_ColumnsToChange = if lst_Columns is null then Table.ColumnNames(tbl_Table) else lst_Columns,
        lst_UpdatedColumns = List.Transform(lst_ColumnsToChange, each fun_Function(_)),
        lst_Zipped = List.Zip({lst_ColumnsToChange, lst_UpdatedColumns}),
        tbl_UpdatedColumns = Table.RenameColumns(tbl_Table, lst_Zipped)
      in
        tbl_UpdatedColumns
in
  fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextFunction
```

```fs
let
  fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextReplace =
    ( tbl_Table as table
    , optional lst_Columns as nullable list
    , optional txt_TextToFind as nullable text
    , optional txt_TextToReplace as nullable text
    ) as table =>
      let
        lst_ColumnsToChange = if lst_Columns is null then Table.ColumnNames(tbl_Table) else lst_Columns,
        lst_UpdatedColumns =
          List.ReplaceValue(
            lst_ColumnsToChange,
            txt_TextToFind,
            txt_TextToReplace,
            Replacer.ReplaceText
          ),
        lst_Zipped = List.Zip({lst_ColumnsToChange,lst_UpdatedColumns}),
        tbl_UpdatedColumns = Table.RenameColumns(tbl_Table, lst_Zipped)
      in
        tbl_UpdatedColumns
in
  fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextReplace
```

---

For example, with this input:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 2 | b | y |
| 3 | c | z |

We can transform it in to this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 2 | b | y |
| 3 | c | z |

By using this code:

```fs
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUoE4gqlWJ1oJSMgKwmIK8E8YyArGYirlGJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t, col3 = _t]),
    TextReplace = fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextReplace(Source, {"col1", "col2"}, "col", "column"),
    TextFunction = fun_RenameColumnsUsingTextFunction(TextReplace, null, Text.Proper)
in
    TextFunction
```

You can see more examples at this helpful GitHub repo: [PowerBI-Helpers](https://github.com/chrimaho/powerbi-helpers)